# using Rcurl with HTTPs

Tags: r, rcurl

I tried the following code in R on windows:

```
library(RCurl)
postForm("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin/",
    "email" = "me@gmail.com",
    "Passwd" = "abcd",
    "service" = "finance",
    "source" = "Test-1"
)
```

but go the following error:

```
Error in postForm()
SL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

How do I setup RCurl to allow use of HTTPs?

Comment: More of a guess than an answer, but does `curlVersion()$protocol` include "https"? If not, then you need to install a version of the curl library with ssl support. How to do that would depend on your operating system (the output of `sessionInfo()` might help)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install a SSL library.

1. For windows you can get one here: [Download "OpenSSL for Windows" version 0.9.8k](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q=)
2. Unzip to a temporary folder, and copy the files "libeay32.dll" and
   "ssleay32.dll" from the "bin" sub-folder to R\library\RCurl\lib\i386.
3. Also you might copy it into the same directory as the R.exe.
4. Then check if you have access to the https protocol:

   ```
   library(RCurl)
   curlVersion()$protocol 
   ## [1] "tftp"   "ftp"    "telnet" "dict"   "ldap"   "http"   "file"   "https"     
   ## [9] "ftps"   "scp"    "sftp"
   ```
5. Then install a new set of credential files:

   ca-bundle.crt can be found at : http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

   rename / copy to ca-bundle.crt
6. Test with this:

   ```
   getURL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin/?service=finance&email=me@gmail.com&Passwd=abcd&source=Test-1", 
          cainfo = "path to R/library/RCurl/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt")
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Very nicely explained.

Comment: @Mscha Vreeburg, I followed your steps, I get this error: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/RCurl/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

Answer (score 13):

just add .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) to your query

```
postForm("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin/",
    "email" = "me@gmail.com",
    "Passwd" = "abcd",
    "service" = "finance",
    "source" = "Test-1",
    .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
```

Comment: This answer is dangerously incorrect. You should not disable verification that the connection is valid without fully understanding the implications of that decision.