# Error: XML Content does not seem to be XML | R 3.1.0

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I am trying to get this XML file, but am unable to. I checked the other solutions in the same topic, but I couldn't understand. I am a R newbie.

```
> library(XML)
> fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
> doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileURL,useInternal=TRUE)
```

**Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml'**

Can you please help?

Comment: Paste the link into chrome address bar and get the message "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it." It then shows the document tree.

Answer (score 52):

Remove the `s` from `https`

```
library(XML)

fileURL<-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(sub("s", "", fileURL), useInternal = TRUE)
class(doc)
## [1] "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `Unknown IO errorfailed to load external entity`

Comment: good one! why does that happen though? (the https ruining the xml read?)

Answer (score 50):

You can use `RCurl` to fetch the content and then XML seems to be able to handle it

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
xData <- getURL(fileURL)
doc <- xmlParse(xData)
```

Comment: Thanks @jdharrison for the reply. I got the following Error Message when I typed the fourth line: XData <- getURL(fileURL).

**Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE): SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed**

What does it mean?

Comment: @ArpanGanguli Use `xData <- getURL(fileURL, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)`. The error is explained in depth at http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html

Comment: should that be omegahat.net ??

Comment: @Sean yes it is now .net  omegahat.net/RCurl/FAQ.html

Answer (score 15):

xmlTreeParse does not support https.

You can load the data with `getURL` (from `RCurl`) and then parse it.

Comment: In other words, replace "HTTPS" with "HTTP"

Comment: The issue is that some sources only provide https URLs.

Answer (score 8):

Answer is at http://www.omegahat.net/RCurl/installed/RCurl/html/getURL.html. Key point is to use ssl.verifyPeer=FALSE with getURL if certificate error is shown.

```
library (RCurl)
library (XML)
curlVersion()$features
curlVersion()$protocol
##These should show ssl and https. I can see these on windows 8.1 at least. 
##It may differ on other OSes.

temp <- getURL("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml", ssl.verifyPeer=FALSE)
DFX <- xmlTreeParse(temp,useInternal = TRUE)
```

If ssl or https capability is not shown by libcurl functions, check [using Rcurl with HTTPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736895/using-rcurl-with-https).

Comment: I think that should now be omegahat.net

Comment: Updated link base URL from omegahat.org to omegahat.net

Answer (score 2):

Using `download.file` avoids introducing another dependency. The following function returns the output of `XML::xmlParse` also when the URL starts with `https`. It caches the file to a temporary directory so that it will be downloaded only once if this function is called many times during an R session.

```
xml_parse <- function(xml_url){
    # Temporary copy of the xml file, valid for this R session
    xml_temp_file <- file.path(tempdir(), basename(xml_url))
    if (!file.exists(xml_temp_file)){
        print(sprintf("Downloading to %s.", xml_temp_file))
        download.file(xml_url, xml_temp_file)
    }
    return(XML::xmlParse(xml_temp_file))
}

# Example
xml_content = xml_parse("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml")
```

Comment: I still get the error mentioned above but I can repeat this until it works for every file.