# Reading XML using R - Error

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I'm trying to scrape xml from this url: data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Potato_2013.xml using R  (version : 3.1.0)

Tried

> library(XML)
>
> url<- "data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Potato_2013.xml"
>
> doc<- xmlParse(url,useInternalNodes=TRUE)

But am getting an error saying

> Error: The XML content does not seem to be xml:

Any way to fix this??

typing just

> doc<-xmlParse(url)

gives a document is empty error.

I am looking to extract the values for the nodes State, Commodity, Arrival Date etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584514/error-xml-content-does-not-seem-to-be-xml-r-3-1-0) SO question:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
##
url<- "data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Potato_2013.xml"
Data <- getURL(url)
doc <- xmlParse(Data)
```

Comment: @Spacedman yes good call; this is a very large file and taking a while to operate on.

Comment: I think `xmlParse(url)` will work if the OP just sticks 'http://' on the URL, but I'm on a slow net at the moment...

Comment: Also, this is the worst kind of XML. It has no line breaks. It looks like a SOAP response. It looks like regular tabular data that would be about 1Mb as a CSV file. By splitting into lines on the <Table> tag its almost trivially readable.

Comment: @Spacedman You should post that as an answer. This file is unreasonably large - I had `xmlToList()` running on `doc` but after about 20 minutes I just killed the command because it was taking forever.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works. And yes getURL does take a while to finish