# Data Scraping with RHTMLForms

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some data from a website with the RHTMLForms package.
First I want to get the form description so I run:

```
library(RHTMLForms)
uBTS <- "https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=289"
fm <- getHTMLFormDescription(uBTS)
```

However when I try that I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=289'
```

I'm not sure if there's an alternative or not or if this is even something to be expected. I'm following an example from a book which actually uses the same website, and there seems to work.

EDIT: I followed the instructions from here [Error: XML Content does not seem to be XML | R 3.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584514/error-xml-content-does-not-seem-to-be-xml-r-3-1-0) but it didn't really solve my problem. Also it seems that the links they suggest are down.