# R: Webscraping: XML content does not seem to be XML

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to webscrape a table.
I tried the code below but it does not work giving an error message:

> XML content does not seem to be XML

```
 library(XML)

 link1 <- "https://www.westmetall.com/en/markdaten.php?action=show_table&field=LME_Cu_cash"
 table1 <-readHTMLTable(link1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 table1
 dd = do.call(rbind,table1)
 dd
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584751/6685140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `getURL()` to obtain the html content, and then use `readHTMLTable`, like this:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl) # for getURL()

link1 <- "https://www.westmetall.com/en/markdaten.php?action=show_table&field=LME_Cu_cash"
html <- getURL(link1)
table1 <-readHTMLTable(html,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Hope it helps.