# Invalid Certificate Change with RWordpress

Tags: r, wordpress, knitr, r-markdown

In following the instructions from http://sites.tufts.edu/emotiononthebrain/2017/08/12/blog-posting-from-r-markdown-to-wordpress/ (which incidentally has a typo capitalizing Press in Wordpress in the setting of options, I get the following error

`Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) :
SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain`

What's going on here? Is there a straightforward fix?

Comment: Could it be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6736895/3358272?

Comment: You might need to inspect the certificates themselves to determine if there is a problem. (iow: this is likely not a problem with R or `RWordpress`, perhaps it's with the website security.)

Comment: BTW: the capital P in WordPress is not a typo. WP even includes a [function to change Wordpress into WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/capital_P_dangit).

Comment: In the code for setting options it is - try and run the code in the blog post without changing it.